# My html code is not work as target blank

Tags: javascript

My html code is not work as target blank, it's not opening new window when clicking.

```
<a onclick="javascript: window.location = 'myurl','_blank'"; ></a>
```

Comment: `window.location` changes the URL of current window, it does not open new window. Use `window.open()` top open URL in new window

Comment: Note: remove the `;` or keep it inside `onclick` attribute, not after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window.open just like @Tushar said in the comment:

```
<a onclick="javascript: window.open('myurl')"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  attribute `href` and `target`

```
<a href="myurl" target="_blank">Your element</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want could be done in pure html:

```
<a href="my_url" target="_blank">Your link text here!</a>
```

It is always best to use html if javascript is not necessarily needed!